# Not able to make predictions in new data

Tags: r, svm

This was working flawlessly with glm and randomForest and was able to make predictions on the new data but doesn't seem to go through for SVM for some reason, please help!

I'm using the e1071 SVM package in R.

```
reg.svm <- svm(survived_str ~ pclass + sex + sibsp + parch + fare + embarked_2 + has_cabin + name_cat_2 + ticket_cat + age_amelia, data = train_2, cost=100, gamma=1, probability=TRUE)

test_2$p.svm <- predict(reg.svm, newdata=test_2)
```

I get this irritating error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "p.svm", value = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L,  : 
  replacement has 332 rows, data has 418
```

However, if I just print the predictions, I get the results

```
predict(reg.svm, newdata=test_2)

  2   3   5   6   7   8  10  11  12  13  15  16  18  19  21  22  23  24  27  28  29 
  1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0 
 30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  40  42  43  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  54 
  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1 
 55  57  58  59  60  62  64  65  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  77  78  79  80 
  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0 
 82  83  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  94  95  96  97  99 100 101 102 103 105 106 107 
  0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1 
108 110 111 113 114 115 116 117 119 121 122 123 124 125 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 
  0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1 
134 135 138 139 140 141 143 144 145 146 147 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 162 163 
  1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1 
165 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 176 177 178 180 184 186 187 188 189 191 192 193 195 
  1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0 
196 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 
  0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0 
219 220 221 222 223 224 226 227 228 229 230 231 233 234 236 238 239 240 241 242 243 
  1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   1 
244 245 246 247 248 249 252 253 254 255 256 257 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 
  0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1 
269 270 271 272 274 276 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 
  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0 
293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300 302 304 305 307 308 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 
  1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0 
319 320 322 323 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 334 335 336 337 338 339 341 342 
  1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0 
343 345 346 348 349 351 353 354 355 356 357 359 360 361 362 363 364 366 367 368 370 
  1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1 
371 372 373 374 375 377 378 379 380 381 382 383 384 385 386 388 389 390 391 392 393 
  0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1 
397 398 400 401 403 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 414 415 416 417 
  1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0 
Levels: 0 1
```

Comment: are there `NA` values in your training or prediction set?

Comment: yes but not in the variables used in the model formula. there are some unused variables in the dataset

Comment: well, what happens if you remove those unused variables?  (To get much farther we will need a reproducible example ...)

Comment: i removed everything except the required variables and the ID variables and it worked fine. I'd assume this as a best practice now on unless there was some other issue! Thanks!

Comment: @PreritAhuja you can add your solution as an answer to your own question, that is perfectly acceptable here on SO. In that way it will be more obvious what the solution is, and you can gather some reputation ;).

Comment: It may be worth reporting this issue (probably best to remain neutral and call it an "issue" rather than a "bug") to the `e1071` maintainers (`maintainer("e1071")`), as this does seem like somewhat surprising/unwanted behaviour